# Requirement not fulfiled at heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, ubuntu-18.04

I am getting the error while deploying Django project on heroku.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_3724e729_/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_3724e729_/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

I tried reinstalling apturl and I can see below- unpacking aptutl 0.5.2 but still I am getting error at heroku.

```
 sudo apt-get install apturl apturl-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  efibootmgr libboost-program-options1.65.1 libegl1-mesa libfwup1
  libgoogle-perftools4 libllvm9 libpcrecpp0v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4
  libwayland-egl1-mesa libyaml-cpp0.5v5 linux-headers-5.4.0-45-generic
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-42 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-45
  linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-45-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-45-generic mongo-tools mongodb-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libgtk2-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apturl apturl-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
Need to get 19.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 228 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apturl-common amd64 0.5.2ubuntu14.2 [10.9 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apturl amd64 0.5.2ubuntu14.2 [8,464 B]
Fetched 19.4 kB in 1s (31.2 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package apturl-common.
(Reading database ... 229913 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apturl-common_0.5.2ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apturl-common (0.5.2ubuntu14.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apturl.
Preparing to unpack .../apturl_0.5.2ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apturl (0.5.2ubuntu14.2) ...
Setting up apturl-common (0.5.2ubuntu14.2) ...
Setting up apturl (0.5.2ubuntu14.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

Comment: `apturl` is a system package not a python package. It is installed through `apt` not `python` or `pip`. You've been using the [Python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) where the dependencies are installed through `requirements.txt` (or `Pipfile` or `setup.py`). You need the [Apt buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) where the dependencies are installed through `Aptfile`.

Comment: @TinNguyen. Please check above I did sudo apt-get only, not pip install.

Comment: I am aware. When you however deploy an app your build environment is reset. You can't write `sudo apt-get install apturl apturl-common`. When you deploy the app your app won't deploy in the first place. That's the correct step if you are working on a Ubuntu machine you have full control over. A machine whose file system doesn't get wiped after each code commit.

Comment: @TinNguyen. Can you please explain to me what I should do? I am new to this and don't know much about it.

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app You need https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.  
For Python you probably had a file named `requirements.txt`. For Apt you need an `Aptfile`. How that works is described on their GitHub. The Apt buildpack needs to run before the Python multiple (see linked article) so when the Python checks for `apturl` it is already installed and nothing needs to be done there.